# How to scrape the non loaded content of the page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have made a script that will scrape link to concerns. But the page are not fully loaded. In bottom of the page is button "Pokaż więcej" that means show more. If I click that it will load more concerns. This script scrape only the first part. How can I scrape whole list?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.gpw.pl/spolki"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
x = soup.find_all("a")

tuple = []
for link in x:
    tuple.append(link.get("href"))

finalTuple = []

for x in tuple:
    if "spolka?isin=" in x:
        finalTuple.append(x)

print(finalTuple)
```

Comment: You have 2 options. 1. Use selenium, click the "load more" element and parse the page. 2. Use requests and determine what form-data is submitted when you press load more. The first one seems to be easier.

Comment: use DevTool in Chrome/Firefox (tab: "Network") to see all requests send from browser to serwer - if you filter `XHR` (AJAX) requests then you may find use used by JavaScript to get data when you press "Pokaż więcej". And then you can use it with requests. Usually it send JSON data which can be easy converted to Python dictionary/list and you don't have to scrape HTML. (PL: powodzenia)

Comment: when you press "Pokaż więcej then JavaScript uses url https://www.gpw.pl/ajaxindex.php  to send `POST` request with data `offset` to get next values.

Comment: +1 furas, I didn't look that far. If the AJAX on this one is that simple, that would be a better answer than mine below.

Comment: @aneroid as you mentioned in your answer work with Selenium is simpler and I still don't have working code for my answer :)

Comment: FWIW, both furas' and SIM's solutions directly answer your question, and using the same tools as your script, rather than my vague how-to.

Answer (score 3):

You have some options, #3 is the most likely viable:

1. find a way to trigger the Javascript which loads more data and get that page data with [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)
2. find what URL is actually fetching the new data (if there is one) and use that with requests

   - edit: [see Furas' comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481586/how-to-scrap-the-non-loaded-content-of-the-page/61482599#comment108760230_61481586). In your case, that may be a simpler/quicker solution. You could also completely avoid loading the original page in BS4 if that AJAX endpoint provides all "concerns" data
3. or use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). That automates the browser, as well as user actions. It may be slower than just bs4 + requests but it creates an actual browser session with a loaded web page, javascript executed in the browser, etc. So you don't need to figure out which JS does what.

In taking a brief look at the page you linked, it's non-obvious what source is providing the new data. So selenium is the favoured choice.

See these answers which solve similar problems:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17436663/1431750
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51991648/1431750
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31864214/1431750

---

Btw, **`tuple = []`** and **`finalTuple = []` ?** C'mon! You are creating an empty *list* `[]` and assigning it to a variable [*`tuple`* which is a different data structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and overriding the name/constructor of that data structure. `links` and `final_links` would have been better names - and more meaningful - without overriding the name of Python built-ins, or using a var name that conflicts with the structure of the data it holds/points to.

Answer (score 3):

Although furas has already provided you with a working solution, I thought to come up with mine. If you try the way I've shown below, you don't need to hardcode the parameters. The script should fetch you all the required links traversing all the pages no matter how many they are.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.gpw.pl/spolki'
post_url = 'https://www.gpw.pl/ajaxindex.php'
offset = 0

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}

    for item in list(payload):
        if item.startswith('country'):
            payload[item] = 'on'
        elif item.startswith('voivodship'):
            payload[item] = 'on'
        elif item.startswith('index'):
            payload[item] = 'on'

    while True:
        r = s.post(post_url,data=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
        if not soup.select("tr"):break
        for elem in soup.select("tr"):
            target_links = elem.select_one("a[href^='spolka?isin=']")['href']
            print(target_links)

        offset+=10
        payload['offset'] = offset
```

Answer (score 2):

This page uses `JavaScript` (`AJAX`/`XHR`) to load data when you click `Pokaż więcej`

Using `DevTool` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab: `Network`, filter: `XHR`) I check urls when I press `Pokaż więcej` and I found

https://www.gpw.pl/ajaxindex.php

Browser sends `POST` request with data `offset` and `limit` to read next data.

Using `offset = 0` you can read even data for first page.

Maybe using bigger `limit` (and bigger `offset`) you could read more data in one requests.

`POST` sends many other values which I also add in code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_first_page():

    url = "https://www.gpw.pl/spolki"

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    x = soup.find_all("a")

    tuple = []
    for link in x:
        tuple.append(link.get("href"))

    finalTuple = []

    for x in tuple:
        if "spolka?isin=" in x:
            finalTuple.append(x)

    print('\n'.join(finalTuple))


def get_next_data(offset):

    url = 'https://www.gpw.pl/ajaxindex.php'

    data = {
        "offset": offset,
        "limit": "10",

        "action": "GPWCompanySearch",
        "start": "ajaxSearch",
        "page": "spolki",
        "format": "html",
        "lang": "PL",
        "letter": "",
        "order": "",
        "order_type": "",
        "searchText": "",
        "index[empty]": "on",
        "index[WIG20]":"on",
        "index[mWIG40]":"on",
        "index[sWIG80]":"on",
        "index[WIG30]":"on",
        "index[WIG]":"on",
        "index[WIGdiv]":"on",
        "index[WIG-CEE]":"on",
        "index[WIG-Poland]":"on",
        "index[InvestorMS]":"on",
        "index[TBSP.Index]":"on",
        "index[CEEplus]":"on",
        "index[mWIG40TR]":"on",
        "index[NCIndex]":"on",
        "index[sWIG80TR]":"on",
        "index[WIG-banki]":"on",
        "index[WIG-budownictwo]":"on",
        "index[WIG-chemia]":"on",
        "index[WIG-energia]":"on",
        "index[WIG-ESG]":"on",
        "index[WIG-górnictwo]":"on",
        "index[WIG-informatyka]":"on",
        "index[WIG-leki]":"on",
        "index[WIG-media]":"on",
        "index[WIG-motoryzacja]":"on",
        "index[WIG-nieruchomości]":"on",
        "index[WIG-odzież]":"on",
        "index[WIG-paliwa]":"on",
        "index[WIG-spożywczy]":"on",
        "index[WIG-telekomunikacja]":"on",
        "index[WIG-Ukraine]":"on",
        "index[WIG.GAMES]":"on",
        "index[WIG.MS-BAS]":"on",
        "index[WIG.MS-FIN]":"on",
        "index[WIG.MS-PET]":"on",
        "index[WIG20TR]":"on",
        "index[WIG30TR]":"on",
        "index[WIGtech]":"on",
        "sector[510]":"510","sector[110]":"110","sector[750]":"750","sector[410]":"410","sector[310]":"310","sector[360]":"360","sector[740]":"740","sector[180]":"180","sector[220]":"220","sector[650]":"650","sector[350]":"350","sector[320]":"320","sector[610]":"610","sector[690]":"690","sector[660]":"660","sector[330]":"330","sector[820]":"820","sector[399]":"399","sector[150]":"150","sector[640]":"640","sector[540]":"540","sector[140]":"140","sector[830]":"830","sector[520]":"520","sector[210]":"210","sector[170]":"170","sector[730]":"730","sector[420]":"420","sector[185]":"185","sector[370]":"370","sector[630]":"630","sector[130]":"130","sector[620]":"620","sector[720]":"720","sector[710]":"710","sector[810]":"810","sector[430]":"430","sector[120]":"120","sector[450]":"450","sector[160]":"160","sector[530]":"530","sector[440]":"440",
        "country[POLSKA]":"on","country[AUSTRALIA]":"on","country[AUSTRIA]":"on","country[Belgia]":"on","country[BUŁGARIA]":"on","country[CYPR]":"on","country[CZECHY]":"on","country[DANIA]":"on","country[ESTONIA]":"on","country[FRANCJA]":"on","country[GLOBAL]":"on","country[GUERNSEY]":"on","country[HISZPANIA]":"on","country[HOLANDIA]":"on","country[INNY]":"on","country[IRLANDIA]":"on","country[KANADA]":"on","country[LITWA]":"on","country[LUKSEMBURG]":"on","country[NIEMCY]":"on","country[Norwegia]":"on","country[REPUBLIKA+CZESKA]":"on","country[SŁOWACJA]":"on","country[Słowenia]":"on","country[STANY+ZJEDNOCZONE]":"on","country[SZWAJCARIA]":"on","country[SZWECJA]":"on","country[UKRAINA]":"on","country[WĘGRY]":"on","country[WIELKA+BRYTANIA]":"on","country[WŁOCHY]":"on","country[JERSEY]":"on",
        "voivodship[11]":"on","voivodship[16]":"on","voivodship[5]":"on","voivodship[13]":"on","voivodship[17]":"on","voivodship[7]":"on","voivodship[2]":"on","voivodship[10]":"on","voivodship[8]":"on","voivodship[4]":"on","voivodship[15]":"on","voivodship[9]":"on","voivodship[6]":"on","voivodship[3]":"on","voivodship[12]":"on","voivodship[14]":"on"
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    x = soup.find_all("a")

    tuple = []
    for link in x:
        tuple.append(link.get("href"))

    finalTuple = []

    for x in tuple:
        if "spolka?isin=" in x:
            finalTuple.append(x)

    print('\n'.join(finalTuple))

#get_first_page() # you don't need it if you use `offset 0`

for offset in range(0, 10, 10):
    print('---', offset, '---')
    get_next_data(offset)
```

Comment: Nice one! It's that post `data` with the tons of extra fields that makes it harder to accomplish, but definitely more efficient than selenium exec speed + memory usage.